# Cannot build master of Tensorflow Serving

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I've built Tensorflow from source, CUDA 8.0, python 3.5, Ubuntu 16.04, targeting a NVIDIA 1070, and it works fine.

> Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul  5 2016, 12:43:10)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on
>   linux Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more
>   information.
>
> > > > import tensorflow as tf I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA
> > > >         library libcublas.so.8.0 locally I
> > > >         tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA
> > > >         library libcudnn.so.5 locally I
> > > >         tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA
> > > >         library libcufft.so.8.0 locally I
> > > >         tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA
> > > >         library libcuda.so.1 locally I
> > > >         tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:108] successfully opened CUDA
> > > >         library libcurand.so.8.0 locally

However, when attempting to build tensorflow_serving from source, it always fails as such:

> Blockquote
>    File "/home/alitz/.cache/bazel/_bazel_alitz/7318bb8e61ee048c2d10c9f8fb67c783/execroot/serving/bazel-out/host/bin/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/example/export_half_plus_two.runfiles/tf_serving/../org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/example/export_half_plus_two.py", line 115, in 
>       tf.app.run()
>     File "/home/alitz/.cache/bazel/_bazel_alitz/7318bb8e61ee048c2d10c9f8fb67c783/execroot/serving/bazel-out/host/bin/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/example/export_half_plus_two.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
>       sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
>     File "/home/alitz/.cache/bazel/_bazel_alitz/7318bb8e61ee048c2d10c9f8fb67c783/execroot/serving/bazel-out/host/bin/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/example/export_half_plus_two.runfiles/tf_serving/../org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/example/export_half_plus_two.py", line 111, in main
>       Export()
>     File "/home/alitz/.cache/bazel/_bazel_alitz/7318bb8e61ee048c2d10c9f8fb67c783/execroot/serving/bazel-out/host/bin/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/example/export_half_plus_two.runfiles/tf_serving/../org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/example/export_half_plus_two.py", line 106, in Export
>       assets_callback=CopyAssets)
>     File "/home/alitz/.cache/bazel/_bazel_alitz/7318bb8e61ee048c2d10c9f8fb67c783/execroot/serving/bazel-out/host/bin/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/example/export_half_plus_two.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/exporter.py", line 202, in init
>       graph_any_buf.Pack(copy)
>   AttributeError: 'Any' object has no attribute 'Pack'
>   Blockquote

Any help would be greatly appreciated, or I will quit my job and go work construction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Though I built protobuf from source, apparently this wasn't enough.

Steps to fix:

sudo pip uninstall protobuf
sudo pip install --upgrade protobuf==3.0.0b2

This version, and only this version, seems to work with the master for tensorflow_serving, at least for me.